# Given an array of indexes, how can I filter an array in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Given an array of indexes I would like to get a subarray of myArray, with the items at those indexes.
I'm currently iterating the indexes array to create a subarray, but I'm wondering if this can be achieved by using the .filter function.

```
var indexes = [3,4,9,11]
myArray.filter(...)
```

Comment: `filter` would be inefficient because it would look at each value in `myArray`. Consider what would happen if `myArray` had 100 thousand items.  Your method of iterating the indexes array would loop 4 times, but filter would loop (internally) 100 thousand times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that

- the given indices are in *increasing* order, and
- all indices are *valid* for  the array (i.e. less than the 
  number of elements),

then a simple map operation would work:

```
let indexes = [2, 4, 7]
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

let filtered = indexes.map { myArray[$0] }
print(filtered) //["c", "e", "h"]
```

*Remark:* In earlier Swift releases, there was a `PermutationGenerator`
exactly for this purpose:

```
let filtered = Array(PermutationGenerator(elements: myArray, indices: indexes))
print(filtered) //["c", "e", "h"]
```

However, this has been deprecated in Swift 2.2 and will be removed
in Swift 3. I haven't seen a Swift 3 replacement yet.

Comment: mhm this sounds cool. The 2 requirements are always satisfied. Is this solution more efficient than iterating?

Comment: @Patrick: You should test it. I am pretty sure that `map()` iterates internally as well. – Possible advantages compared to an explicit loop are: Shorter functional code, and the result is a *constant*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain why the first assumption is required "the given indices are in increasing order" ? I can't see a reason why it won't work even if this assumption is broken. Thank you.

Comment: @NikolaySuvandzhiev: I assumed that the intension is to get a “subarray” of elements in their original order (as with  the filter method). If the order does not matter then that restriction is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try, although that's far away from efficient. But that's what you get if you insist on using filter

```
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var indexes = [1, 3]
myArray.filter { (vowel) -> Bool in
    if let index = myArray.indexOf(vowel) {
        return indexes.contains(index)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Do you think that this is more efficient than an iteration?

Comment: noway :D I couldn't think of any efficient way to do it in filter

Comment: I see, ok then best way is to iterate, I guess.

Comment: There may be unexpected results if the array elements are not unique (since `indexOf` returns the index of the *first* occurrence).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flatMap to retrieve the filtered subArray

```
let indexes = [2, 4, 7]
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

let subArray = indexes.flatMap { (index) -> String? in
    return (0 <= index && index < myArray.count) ? myArray[index] : nil
}
```